# Can you start wget from a specific file?

Tags: windows, wget

I'm attempting to use wget (on Windows) on a url that hosts a few thousand files. If I sit at my PC, it seems to work fine all day long. If I leave my PC overnight the connection just drops randomly with no reference to an error or timeout. Because of this, I never end up capturing the full directory meaning I have to start all over again. Is there a way that I can use wget after a specific file?

Example:
Directory contains files "A,B,C,D,.,.,.,.X,Y,Z".
Wget gets files A, B and C.
Can I start wget at file C (or after) to grab only items that I haven't downloaded yet? I'm trying to avoid wget looking through my current directory of files and comparing them to the URL to see whether or not I have them.

Comment: Portable devive with sleep enabled?

Comment: I should note that I found that the -c switch should work, but it doesn't look like it is. From the information I read, it looks like it doesn't play nicely with -r and this is likely why I'm having a problem. I also noticed that there is a wait in the wget command I'm using. I removed the wait to see if it grabs the files in a more reasonable period of time. Hopefully, as a workaround, will resolve my issue. EDIT: Information I've been reading is here: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html